# How to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[2^{n}z^{n!}]$

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried with $$1/R = \lim_{n\to\infty}{\sup({\sqrt[n]{2^n}})} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{2} = 2$$

But that don't seem correct.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What you computed is the radius of convergence for $\sum 2^n z^n$.  For radius of convergence of $\sum 2^n z^{n!}$ you should use the $n!$ order root of $2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\sqrt[n]{2^n\left|z^{n!}\right|}= 2|z|^{(n-1)!} \to \begin{cases}0&,|z|<1\\\\2&,|z|=1\\\\\infty&,|z|>1\end{cases}$$

and the series converges when $|z|<1$ and diverges otherwise.